# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ball_anim/com.example.ball_anim.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

hi i have a "strange" problem with my code this is what log says:

```
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ball_anim/com.example.ball_anim.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at com.example.ball_anim.Main$MyView.<init>(Main.java:86)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at com.example.ball_anim.Main.onCreate(Main.java:48)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     ... 11 more
```

the error appears when calling class custom methods GameTime in the Main class..this is my class GameTime.java

```
public class GameTime extends CountDownTimer{
    public long Tempo_Trascorso;
    private final long startTime = 10000;
    private boolean End=false;
    private long Tempo_Stop;

        public GameTime(long startTime, long interval){
            super(startTime, interval);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish(){
                  System.out.println("Finish!");
                  End = true;

                }

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                    System.out.println("Time Restante:" + millisUntilFinished);
                    Tempo_Trascorso = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
                    if(End == false){
                    Tempo_Stop=millisUntilFinished;
                     }
                    }
                //Custom method #1 get the time when the game thread is stopped
                public long getLastTime(){ 
                    return Tempo_Stop;
                }
                //Custom method #2 get the true/false when the time is end
                public boolean getEndGame(){
                    return End;
                }


}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {
private Bitmap Player_bmp,Player_bmp_StateLV1,Player_bmp_StateLV2,Player_bmp_StateLV3,Life_bmp,Lose_bmp;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private AnimationThread AnimThread;
private GameTime GameTime;
private DialogBox Dbox;
private Random rnd;
private int Display_width,Display_height;
private int RandomPosx;
private int Rosso,Verde,Blu;
private Paint paint,paint_L;
private float deltaX,deltaY;
private boolean Drag = false,Collision = false,Stop = false;
private int Static_PositionX,Static_PositionY;
private List<Sfere> C_Sfere = new ArrayList<Sfere>();
private int Life,LostLife=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));


    }
public class MyView extends SurfaceView {

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
// More code(too long)

}
```

Edit: this is the OnCreate of the main and myview class when create surfaceview and game stuff, do not place all of the code because it is too long,if need more info tell me;)

anywhere in the main class, call the custom methods of the application GameTime gives me. I want to clarify that where the main class gives me error in the class dedicated to the dialogbox (for example) do not have errors error

Comment: Have a look at the line 48 of `at com.example.ball_anim.Main.onCreate(Main.java:48)` and check what might be null.

Comment: You've got a null pointer exception. Did you run this through a debugger?

Comment: i added Main.java @ZouZou i see the error on Line 48 but i don't understood where is the error xD

Comment: @Keyren Post the line 48

Comment: @ZouZou the line 48 is : `setContentView(new MyView(this));`

Comment: @Keyren Line 86 sorry. Something might be null here

Comment: @ZouZou the Line 86 is the line where call my custom methods for example `GameTime.getLastTime()` now the same error is in line 59

Comment: @Keyren You forgot to initialize your GameTime object.

Comment: @ZouZou LOL I'm so stupid, I had completely forgotten >_< i'have try and work now really thanks ZouZou^^

Answer (score 2):

Having a `NullPointerException` is one of the most common error you'll get when writing a program. Hopefully, it's one of the easiest error to fix.

When a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown ?

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an
>   object is required. These include:
>
> - Calling the instance method of a null object.
> - Accessing or modifying
>     the field of a null object.
> - Taking the length of null as if it were an
>     array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an
>     array.
> - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.
> - Applications
>     should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of
>     the null object.

Now that you read the possible cases when it is thrown, learn to read messages from the logcat, they're often informative. In your case the important information to read is from the `Caused By` line :

```
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at com.example.ball_anim.Main$MyView.<init>(Main.java:86)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at com.example.ball_anim.Main.onCreate(Main.java:48)
06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
```

If you look closely, you will see that the error is thrown at the line 86 of your `Main.java` file (i.e `at com.example.ball_anim.Main$MyView.<init>(Main.java:86)`).

So take a look at this line and see what might be `null`. In your case you declared your variable `GameTime` but you forgot to initialize it so when you try to call the method `getLastTime()` on it, a `NPE` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In the log you can see that the exception occurred at

> ```
> 06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 06-15 17:06:38.054: E/AndroidRuntime(5699):     at com.example.ball_anim.Main$MyView.<init>(Main.java:86)
> ```

So you need to check your constructor of `MyView` at line 86 in the file `Main.java`.

You did not post its code so we can't help you more then that.